# How to exit complete Android application

Tags: android

What is the best way to exit complete Android application (not a single activity) when a button is pressed?

I've tried using `finish()` but it only closed the active activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to exit the application is

```
 system.exit(0);
```